# Passing a `struct file` to another process

Tags: linux, file, process, linux-kernel, fork

Imagine I'm developing a kind of system call which receives a `pid_t pid` and returns a file descriptor `fd`. What this syscall's got to do is monitor the process whose pid is `pid` so that, whenever this other process calls `fork()`, something is written to the file descriptor `fd`. To achieve this, I created a new list field in `struct task_struct` called, for example, `files_to_signal_on_fork`. So, my syscall creates a new `struct file *file`, gets the `struct task_struct *task` related to `pid`, add `file` to `task`'s `files_to_signal_on_fork` list and returns the file descriptor representing `file`, so that I can use `poll` to keep track of when the other process calls `fork()`. I added a few lines of code to `do_fork`, so that, when it gets called, it writes something to all the `struct file *` structures stored in the process' `files_to_signal_on_fork` list.

So, is passing a process' `struct file *` structure to another process a good idea? Is there any way to check if the `struct file *`'s owner is still alive before `do_fork` try to write something to it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Files are reference-counted.
You must remove the `struct file` from the task's list when its last reference is removed (`f_op->release`).